# mdb angular navbar is not working in mobile view

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

mdb angular navbar is not working in mobile view

I am new to mdbootstrap in angular and when am checking for mdb-navbar it is not working means when i have configured as routerLink in place of href and trying to click the link in mobile view ,link is opening but navbar is not collapsing. can someone help me on this.

And also there is an another issue like when am trying t put mdb angular scroll bar in services page and ran the program, link is not working as it is pointing to http://localhost:4200/#test1 instead of http://localhost:4200/services#test1.

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Below is the code

```
 <!-- Links -->
 <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
     <li class="nav-item ">
         <a class="nav-link waves-light" mdbRippleRadius routerLink="home">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link waves-light" mdbRippleRadius routerLink="about">About Me</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link waves-light" mdbRippleRadius routerLink="services">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link waves-light" mdbRippleRadius routerLink="contact">Contact US</a>
    </li>

 </ul>
 <!-- Links -->

 <!-- Search form -->
 <!---<form class="form-inline  waves-light" mdbRippleRadius>
     <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
 </form>-->
 <div><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;anu4looks@gmail.com<br>
    <i class="fa fa-mobile-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+91 9951877261</div>
```

Comment: Looks like your are mixing material and bootstrap. Do not do that.

Comment: No, I have not added angular material. only bootstrap(mdb) used.

Comment: OK I see. It's going to be difficult to debug this without more information. Maybe you can create a plunkr

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I can see only the final html output. Without all component's code, I can only suggest that you've missed the proper mdb angular constructions.

To add navbar with mobile responsive behavior you need to add proper mdb angular component - mdb-navbar in your case.

[Link to the official documentation](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/navigation/navbar/#responsive-behaviors)

Code example:

```
<mdb-navbar SideClass="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark indigo">
    <links>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hidden brand</a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </links>
</mdb-navbar>
```

This code works as expected.

> link is not working as it is pointing to http://localhost:4200/#test1 instead of http://localhost:4200/services#test1.

Again, without code example, I can only guess. Looks like you're using [Scrollbar and SmoothScroll](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/advanced/scroll/)

According to the link behavior that you've described - may be a problem in path value in href="#test1".
In case href attribute of the smooth-scroll link has the value `href="/#test1"` it can cause this kind of problem.

Check this value and align it with the example [from the documentation](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/advanced/scroll/).

Code example

```
<!--Navigation links with a Smooth SCroll effect-->
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li>
    <h5><a mdbPageScroll href="#test1">Click to scroll to section 1</a></h5>
  </li>
  <br>
  <li>
    <h5><a mdbPageScroll href="#test2">Click to scroll to section 2</a></h5>
  </li>
  <br>
</ul>

<!--Dummy sections with IDs coressponding with the links above-->
<div id="test1" style="height: 1000px;">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
</div>

<div id="test2" style="height: 1000px;">
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
</div>
```